# No NVIDIA settings except Prime Profiles

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04, nvidia-settings

My machine is an Alienware m15r1 with an NVIDIA RTX 2060 graphics card.
I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed, and I use NVIDIA drivers 440.

Whenever I run `nvidia-settings`, I only get one tab option on the left side, which is PRIME PROFILES. There is no other option available to me.

Here is a screenshot of my *NVIDIA X Server Settings*:

[image: nvidia-settings]

And here is a screenshot from  the terminal output of `nvidia-settings`.

[image: nvidia-settings terminal output]

What can I do to resolve this?

Edit-1: Here's the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` [image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Most likely you need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 added,
Secure boot doesn't help, it was off before.
I turned it on, tried once, then rebooted after switching it off and tried again.
No luck with secure boot.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: it seems like the driver got corrupted or  not installed correctly. have you tried to re-install it? you can do it with:  `sudo apt purge nvidia*` then check `ubuntu-drivers device` to see which driver is the recomended one and try to install it or install with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` - it will install all the recomended ones. reboot after delete is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell 7577 with a GTX 1060 and recently updated to 20.04. As with 18.04/10 the nvidia driver/module had problems detecting the 1060. My solution was to use "nvidia-xconfig" to create an xorg.conf file and then specify the Driver and BusID fields...

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia-440"
    BusID          "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```