# 18.04 to 20.04 broke monitor

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, display-resolution, nomodeset

I am running a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and UEFI.  I tried ubuntu live CD and it worked perfectly including recognizing monitor and setting to correct resolution.  I upgraded ubuntu to 20.04.  On reboot the ubuntu just gets locked at the spinning icon (let it sit for over 30 min with no progress).  In debug I found entries on askubuntu that the issue could be NVIDIA drivers.  I entered GRUB2 with esc, typed e and added nomodeset to the boot line.  Now ubuntu boots and everything seems to work with one exception.  The monitor only offers a resolution of 800x600.

In case it is useful this was my UEFI boot log before I did the nomodeset.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jj57bShK8Y/

In system:about it shows the llvmpipe for graphics. 
lspci correctly recognizes my graphics card is an NVIDIA GTX 1070.

I would appreciate any advice on how to fix the display resolution correctly.  Should I have done something different than nomodeset.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fixed my issue.  I originally had the NVIDIA drivers installed on ubuntu 18.04.  When I moved to 20.04 they got removed.  I used:

After using:
[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)

To enter e and enabling nomodeset I was able to boot into Ubuntu but at a reduced resolution.  Then I used the below entry to fix my issue.

[No NVIDIA settings except Prime Profiles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236143/no-nvidia-settings-except-prime-profiles)

$ubuntu-drivers devices
(notice I think they left out the s for devices in their answer in the link)
Gives a list of the drivers and the recommended driver.

Then I installed it with 
$ sudo apt-get install and the driver
In my case it was 
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440 for the NVIDIA GTX 1070.

Did not show as fixed until reboot.

Notice that I had permanently set nomodeset in GRUB but after installing the driver it was fixed so permanently setting  nomodeset was not necessary.  I just needed to do it once with the e command at GRUB to get into the OS and install the driver.